# Reflection in background - Android

Tags: java, android, reflection

Before I ask this I would like to say I am not asking how exactly do you do this but I am looking for a hint or a nudge in the right direction as I have no code but I would like to work it out myself.

In my android app, I have a plain black background which has a queue of objects on top. These objects scroll side to side (see image). My question is how do I reflect these objects in the background like it is done in the image?

[image]

*I have searched for something similar on google and this webstie but I can't find anything on the matter*

Comment: Unless they're doing something funky like rotating on their y axis as well, your best bet is to simply make the image include the reflection, possibly with a real time crop or something similar.

Comment: @RoyFalk Alright. Thank you